# JavaScript For Loop with user entry error

Tags: javascript, for-loop, largenumber

I am currently dabbling with JavaScript and am doing some simple calculations using for loops and I am attempting to take user info for the Table set they want and the numbers they wish to multiply between e.g.

- Enter Table set: 12
- Enter where to start multiplying from: 3
- Enter how high to multiply: 6

This would print:

1. 12 x 3 = 36
2. 12 x 4 = 48
3. 12 x 5 = 60
4. 12 x 6 = 72

My issue is that when I ask the user to select how high they wish to multiply to, if they select a number greater than 9 it doesn't enter the for loop and prints nothing yet 9 and below works.

This is the simple enough code:

```
   function UserEnteredTables()
   {
       var tableNumber = prompt("Please enter the number tables to use: ");
       var numberLowerLimit = prompt("Please select where you want to start multiplying from: ");
       var numberUpperLimit = prompt("Please select how high to multiply to: ");
       document.write("Before the loop " + numberUpperLimit + "<br/>");

      for (i = numberLowerLimit; i <= numberUpperLimit; i++)
      {
          document.write("Made it inside the loop " + "<br/>");
          document.write(tableNumber + " * " + i + " = " + (i * tableNumber) + "<br/>");
      }
      document.write("After the loop " + numberUpperLimit);
  }
```

*Apologies for any indentation issues, had issues pasting for some reason*

I have attached two images, one where I enter the upper limit to 9 and then one were I enter 10. As you can see the 10 doesn't enter the loop.

I assume that I have missed something very simple but I would appreciate if someone could explain what the issue is or if its something to do with JavaScript loops.

[image: Limit of 9]
[image: Limit of 10]

If there is something wrong with the post or you require some other code to fully understand just let me know.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: could you try printing your lower limit as well ?

Comment: BeNdErR below had the correct answer, I had to parse the user entered data. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the `prompt` value returned: its `typeof` is `string`, while what you want is `number` for the loop to work correctly.

Use `parse()` to extract the numeric value out of the prompt value, see here:

https://jsfiddle.net/jwvj2aab/1/

Note that you will need to handle user input in order to deny anything but numbers